# HP-UX - How can I read a text file from tar archive without extracting it?

Tags: bash, text, tar, cat, hp-ux

I have a `tar` archive which contains several text files. I would like to write a script to display (stdout) the content of a file without extracting it to the current directory.

Actually I would like to do the same as:

```
tar tf myArchive.tar folder/someFile.txt
cat folder/someFile.txt
rm -R folder
```

but without the `rm`...

I tried this way but it didn't work:

```
tar tf myArchive.tar folder/someFile.txt | cat
```

Thanks

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Use `x` to extract, with `f` from archive file. Then add also option `-O` to direct extracted files to standard output.

```
tar xf myArchive.tar folder/someFile.txt -O
```

Comment: Actually it works fine on Linux. But when I run it on a HP-UX machine, the content of the file is not displayed. Instead, the folder is extracted. Is it normal? Any workaround?

Comment: `-O` is probably a GNU specific option of `tar`. Perfunctory with the full `--to-stdout` option?

Comment: You should have a look at the HP-UX manpage of tar: `man tar` to see if a similar option is available.

Comment: Nop... Here is the man of tar on HP-UX: http://www.cs.bgu.ac.il/~arik/usail/man/hpux/tar.1.html.
Nothing interesting in this man. The solution must be tricky!

Comment: Have you tried to create a named pipe with `mkfifo` named after the file you are extracting, and `cat` it while extracting it?

Comment: Do you mean something like: `tar xf myArchive.tar folder/someFile.txt | mkfifo -m 644 folder/someFile.txt | cat`? If yes, this command does not work... The error I got is: `mkfifo: cannot access folder: No such file or directory`.

Comment: No, in the other order. First create the pipe. Then untar the file, in the hope `tar` does no delete and create the file, but only fills it. Then cat it, and last remove the pipe.

Comment: Could you give me the command to run? It would be simpler than words! Thanks

Comment: `mkdir folder ; mkfifo folder/someFile.txt ; tar xf myArchive.tar folder/someFile.txt ; cat folder/someFile.txt ; rm -r folder` The important thing is to check whether tar replaces the pipe or not.

Comment: Well this is not necessary to use mkfifo. `tar xf myArchive.tar folder/someFile.txt ; cat folder/someFile.txt ; rm -R folder` works.

Comment: It works, yes. But it extracts the file content to the filesystem. I was wondering why in the first place you didn't want the file to be extracted to the filesystem. Is it too large?

Comment: No this is just an operational directory and I didn't want to cram unnecessary file into it. But anyway, thanks.

Comment: At last resort, maybe you could compile GNU tar under HP/UX?

Comment: For the record, [a gtar version exists on HP-UX](http://hpux.connect.org.uk/hppd/hpux/Gnu/tar-1.26).

Comment: I find it handier to put all the options together at the start:  `tar -Oxf folder/someFile.txt`, or `-xOf` if you don't like it looking like a hex number.